# Where are the conditional formatting custom formulas?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I would like to use custom formulas in the conditional formatting panel on Google Spreadsheets, such as indicated in that link: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/78413#formulas

The problem is that I don’t have that option in the drop down menu. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The article you reference says that custom formulae only work in the new sheets.  So, have you converted your file to the new Google Sheets?  (https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3544847?hl=en&ref_topic=20322)